# Notepad++ regular expression to remove numbers from the beginning of each line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove numbers from the beginning of each line.

Sample Lines:

```
8399 YOUNG,TEWONIA A \ 18180 
17 ABERNATHY,NED V \ 9045 
627 BARTON,SCOTT D \ 2845 
7 ABBOTT,EWARD JR, A \ 88256
```

After remove:

```
YOUNG,TEWONIA A \ 18180 
ABERNATHY,NED V \ 9045 
BARTON,SCOTT D \ 2845 
ABBOTT,EWARD JR, A \ 88256
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[0-9]+\s*
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple,

```
^\d+\s*
```

OR

```
^\d+\s+
```

use the above regex and then replace the match with an empty string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO6bK8/3)